# Correct interpretation of odds ratio

Tags: odds-ratio, odds

I am wondering what the correct way of interpreting an odds ratio is. For example, suppose we have that the probability of success is $p=0.8$. Then, the odds ratio is:

$$
\frac{p}{1-p} = \frac{0.8}{0.2} = 4
$$

From here, I have read from other posts on stats.stackexchange many different ways of interpretating the ratio.

The first is that the probability of success is $4$x more likely than failure. The other is that the ***odds*** are 4x more likely.

I am wondering which of these is technically correct. Do we need to convert the above first before making the former interpretation?

Comment: What you showed is an odds **not** an odds ratio. So the correct interpretation of the 4 you showed is that the probability of success is 4x larger than the probability of failure, or that you expect to see 4 successes per failure. The odds ratio is a ratio of odds. So say that the odds you showed is the odds off success for men, and for women the odds of success is 2, then the odds ratio is 2: the odds of success for men is twice the odds of success for women.

Comment: @MaartenBuis Thank you. In your example, is there a way to convert the statement into one where I can say: "The chance of success for men is twice the success for women", instead of the odds?

Comment: You would have to have the probability of success for both men and women. The example you've given seems only to give the probability of success for one group.

Comment: If we have both probabilities, would it just be the ratio of the probability of success for men divided by the probability of success for women?

Comment: @user321627 Definitely not. Work it out both ways for a probability of success for men of 0.8 and a probability of success for women 0.6.

Comment: Can you elaborate further? Thanks.

Comment: Your result of $4$ could be read as "four times the odds of an even chance", i.e. an odds ratio of your event compared with the odds of $1$ of an event with $p=0.5$.  Clearly $0.8$ is not four times $0.5$ so you event is not four times as likely, but $0.8/0.2$ is four times $0.5/0.5$

Comment: @Henry I am wondering how the above can be interpreted without usage of the term "odds". Can I say that the "probability of success is $0.8/0.5 = 1.6$ times the chance of a failure?

Comment: No - you can say if $p=0.8$ then the probability of success is $4$ times the probability of failure